# change color of cell of dynamicly created datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a dynamic set of datagrids showing queues (of states of production items) populated from database

```
'The datagridviews have already been created at form load.

'get the Qs list - returns datatable with list of queuenames.
    Qlist = dbconnect.dbCall("SELECT * FROM QueueList")

   For iQlist = 0 To Qlist.Rows.Count - 1
'iterate the queue List and populate the datagridview for showing that queue with any items in that queue

     listContents = dbconnect.dbCall("SELECT itemName,queueEntryTime FROM " & Qlist.Rows(iQlist).Item("Q_name"))

      'get the dynamic name of the datagridview 
      Dim controlName = "dg_" & Qlist.Rows(iQlist).Item("Q_name")

      'assign the datatable containing its items to that datagridview
      Me.tabQsAndServiceBays.Controls.Item(controlName).dataSource = listContents

      'want to colour items in each datagrid that are over certain age.
      'i.e. the items is in production queue for too long, something has gone wrong.

      For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In tabQsAndServiceBays.Controls.Item(controlName).rows
            'condition for each row based on cell's contents, if > 20mins mark different color.
             If tabQsAndServiceBays.Controls.Item(controlName).Cells("queueEntryTime").Value > Now - 20 Then
                 dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
             End If
    'next


Next
```

I get a `Public member 'rows' on type 'DataGrid' not found` error.

How come I can reference the `.datasource` property of the datagrid view but not the `.rows`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the actual error msg, `'DataGrid'` and not `'DataGridView'`, then it appears that NET thinks you are using a DataGrid which is not interchangable with the DGV. Here:

```
' 'item' is not needed, removed to prevent scroll
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In tabQsAndServiceBays.Controls(controlName).rows
```

Here there are 2 possible errors.  First, the DataGridViewRow can only be used with a DGV, so no matter what, if you are using a DataGrid, that will fail.  Second, DataGrids do not have a public Rows property.  DataGrid controls are/were for backward compatibility and IIRC, you basically accessed rows via the underlying ADO dataset.

Comment: You are quite right.  The definition for one set of datagridviews, I'd changed, but I'd forgotten to change the other.  Amazing how a simple error can result in hours of head scratching.  I knew I'd changed it from datagrid to datagrid view, but in the wrong place.  Thanks for the help!